# Implementing merge sort algorithm in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort

I'm trying to implement merge sort algorithm in JavaScript. But I'm getting a strange behavior when it comes to merging two sorted arrays.

When I pass those two arrays: `[1,4, 5]` and `[3, 6, 7, 10]` to the merge function, I always get this result: `[ 1, 3, 4, 6, 7 ]`. Strangely without the element `5` and `10` !

Here's my function:

```
function merge(a, b)
{
    var result = [],
        k = 0,
        i = 0,
        j = 0;

    while(a.length > i+1 && b.length > j+1){
        if(a[i] <= b[j]){
            result[k++] = a[i++];
        } else {
            result[k++] = b[j++];
        }
    }

    while(a.length > i+1) {
        result[k++] = a[i++];
    }

    while(b.length > j+1) {
        result[k++] = b[j++];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Take debugger and debug it. A hint: what `a.length > i+1` expression means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `i + 1` by `i` and `j + 1` by `j` in all while loops' conditions and it will work properly. Currently the last elements of `a` and `b` are just ignored because their indices are `a.length - 1` and `b.length - 1`, respectively.